# Google Dataflow - How to specify the TextIO in java if writing to an On-prem server?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

Google Dataflow - How to specify the TextIO if writing to an On-prem server from Dataflow? (Provided that the On-prem server is connected to GCP with Cloud VPN)

```
pipeline.apply("Writer",TextIO.write().to("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX://tmp/somedirectory/somefilename");
```

Does providing the On-prem IP and directory like in above work, when running the Dataflow job? I tried, and the job completed successfully with elements added in the step summary, but i don't see any files written in the on-prem server.
[Not sure if it has anything to do with the authentication with the on-prem server]

Answer (score 2):

Apache beam textio requires a file system to be specified with a schema prefix, eg file:// gs:// hdfs:// . without any of these I believe it defaults to local file.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/review-of-input-streaming-connectors-for-apache-beam-and-apache-spark

So given the 'filename' you specified does not have a schema, I suspect that it will be written to the local disk of the workers, which is not very useful!

So, as @ajp suggests, you need to write to, eg, GCS and then get your on-prem server to read from GCS. - you can perhaps use a pub/sub message as a signal to the on-prem server that the results are ready

Answer (score 1):

Using the IP address and path this way will not work with [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html), it would only work with the file path if your run your pipeline in local.

For remote file transfer to an on-premise server from Cloud Dataflow, the best way is to write files in a Cloud Storage bucket first, like so:

```
pipeline.apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteFilesOnPremise")
   .to("gs://myPipelineBucket/onPremiseFiles")
```

Then either directly download files from the bucket to your on-premise filesystem from your local console with the [gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), or programmatically with the [Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) methods, or you can [mount the bucket as filesystem with Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) on your on-premise system.